# How can you add a method to JavaScripts existing Date() function

Tags: javascript, function, methods, prototype

I am trying to add extend new methods to javascripts existing Date() function in my script so the new method is inherited and can be called over again.

```
Date.prototype.IsLeapYear = function() {
    year = Date.getFullYear();
    return (year % 400) ? ((year % 100) ? ((year % 4) ? false : true) : false) : true;
}
```

for example Date.IsLeapYear would return true or false.

Comment: If you want to call it like `Date.IsLeapYear()` then you just put it on `Date` itself, not on the `prototype`. You put methods on `prototype` for instances

Comment: Thank You for all your help I now have    Date.prototype.IsLeapYear = function() {
    year = this.getFullYear();
    return (year % 400) ? ((year % 100) ? ((year % 4) ? false : true) : false) : true;
};

var Today = new Date();
alert(Today.IsLeapYear());

Comment: While you've gotten a lot of advice about *how* to extend prototyps, in general this is considered a bad idea -- unless you are "monkey patching" standardized functions that don't exist in older browsers.  Short reason why: If the standards community ever adds as "IsLeapYear" method that works differently than yours, things can break.

Answer (score 0):

You did it correctly by extending the prototype.  But if you want to call a function attached to the Date prototype you can do it like this.

```
var leapyear = new Date()
leapyear.IsLeapYear()
```

Comment: never mind I got it to work.. Thank your for the help.  I had a mistype when I went to call the new Method.  LOL Thank Yoy

Answer (score 0):

I think you're very close here, but I did notice a small problem in your IsLeapYear function. Rather than calling "Date.getFullYear()", you'll need to use "this" due to scoping.

```
Date.prototype.IsLeapYear = function() {
    year = this.getFullYear();
    return (year % 400) ? ((year % 100) ? ((year % 4) ? false : true) : false) : true;
};

var d = new Date();
alert(d.IsLeapYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a few things to note:

- There is a major difference between the Date constructor function and the Date.prototype object. Objects in javascript inherit from the prototype of a constructor. Date.getFullYear doesn't exist, it is rather Date.prototype.getFullYear. Therefore in your code, it would have to be called on an instance of a date (this) not the date constructor itself
- While you probably won't notice this, your 'year' variable would become a global variable; remember to declare variables with var (or const if you use es6)

With those small fixes your function will behave as intended.

Comment: "use strict" would also have caught the `var`-less variable.